# how to do sql left join in rails between instance variable and table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

If i have an instance variable say `@data` with attributes `data1` and `data2` and i have table say `details` with attributes `data1` and `details`.
how can i perform sql left join in between instance variable and table joining on data1 columns and return `data2` column from `@data` variable?

I tried to do this but no luck

```
@result = @data.left_outer_joins(:details).select(@data.data2)
```

Comment: A join in this sense is a SQL concept, not a Ruby or a Rails one. You can only join a table to another table. Rails ActiveRecord provides the mechanism to create SQL joins between tables, but that does not change the fundamental nature of a join. Is `@data` an ActiveRecord Relation or a single record?

Comment: @data is calculated based on join between two ActiveRecord relations

Comment: OK, then you can probably join it to your `details` table, but you will need to know on what fields you are joining. What are the two tables that are joined to result in @data, and what is the relationship between `details` and those two tables?